# Function configuration has changed cause 'Get Web App Publishing Profile'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm struggle with very werid scenarion and seems to be hopeless to resolve it. I have *Azure Function* which I use for pretty long time. Cause of that it starts with **FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION** ~2 on **dotnet** but it was upgraded few times and now require **FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION** ~4 and I move it to **dotnet-isolated**. It is working in that runtime for pretty long but recently I notice that from time to time (sometimes once per month, sometimes once per week) it change **FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION** and **FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME** back to old values and cause of that it is not working anymore.

Now funny part. In activity log I found that configuration has change cause **Get Web App Publishing Profile** Event initiated by some randome guid (don't know what it is). And this could happend even in middle of night when noone doing anything with development.

> Operation name
> Get Web App Publishing Profile
> Time stamp
> Mon Nov 28 2022 09:59:06 GMT+0100 (czas środkowoeuropejski standardowy)
> Event initiated by
> 4b11a3b9-2f77-4a46-9d0c-cafda9296e6f

1. How can I trace what really fire up this event?
2. Is it possible to stop it? Make readonly those configuration or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I trace what really fire up this event?

1. You can trace all the app services events by enabling ***change analysis*** in `Diagnose and solve problems -> Availability and Performance` under your webapp/function App.

[image]

2. `Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile` includes all the publishing events with the user profile name in a given subscription by adding `resourcegroupname`as well.

[image]

If your function app/webapp created with service principal authentication, you can trace the details by providing `-objectID` or filter with `AppID`.

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "APPID eq <appID>"
```

[image]

> Is it possible to stop it? Make read-only those configurations or something like that?

1. Restrict actions via `service principal` under `AzureAD` to avoid these kinds of issues.
2. You cannot restrict access to any specific function's configuration. Instead, you can enable [Microsoft.Web/sites/config/read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#permissions) kind of permissions for an App Service.
3. You can define [access restriction rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#manage-access-restriction-rules-in-the-portal) by providing IP range within a chosen network.

   **Goto** your App and choose `Networking`.

[image]